# Pandas: number of subgroups per index

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with index `index1` and values `val1` and `val2`. I'm trying to return the count of unique `val1` values for each `index1`.

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index1', 'val1', 'val2'], data=[['A', 1, 1], ['A', 1, 1], ['A', 2, 1]])

df = df.set_index(['index1'])
```

I group like this

```
groupby = df.groupby([df.index, 'val1'])
```

Then, I call size(), which returns

```
    index1  val1
    A       1       2
            2       1
    dtype: int64
```

This returns the count for each group. I am looking for the number of groups each `index1` value has. I.e `A` has 2 unique groups.

Comment: you want `df.count(level=0)` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Comment: you could do `groupby.size().count(level=0)` but it depends on what output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) if need count unique value in some column per groups:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0)['val1'].nunique() 
print (df1)
index1
A    2
Name: val1, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0)['val1'].nunique().reset_index().rename(columns={'val1':'uniq'})
print (df1)
  index1  uniq
0      A     2
```

And if need count unique values in all columns use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `nunique`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: x.nunique())
print (df1)
        val1  val2
index1            
A          2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total number of unique items for each column you can do the following

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: len(x.unique()))

        val1  val2
index1            
A          2     1
```